# Display full tax info in PDF totals with tax rate as title

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, pdf

I am using this code to display full tax info in PDF totals:

```
public function getTotalsForDisplay()
{
    $store = $this->getOrder()->getStore();
    $config= Mage::getSingleton('tax/config');
    if ($config->displaySalesTaxWithGrandTotal($store)) {
        return array();
    }

    $fontSize = $this->getFontSize() ? $this->getFontSize() : 7;
    $_fullInfo = $this->getOrder()->getFullTaxInfo();
    $total = array();

    $amount = $this->getOrder()->formatPriceTxt($this->getAmount());
    $label = 'gesetzliche MwSt:';
    $total[] = array(
        'amount'    => $amount,
        'label'     => $label,
        'font_size' => $fontSize
    );
    foreach ($_fullInfo as $info) {
        $percent    = $info['percent'];
        $amount     = $info['amount'];
        $rates      = $info['rates'];
        $total[] = array(
           'amount'    => $this->getOrder()->formatPriceTxt($amount),
           'label'     => $rates[0]['title'].' ',
           'font_size' => $fontSize-1
       );
    }


    return $total;
```

While this is working fine, it will output the tax rate title as label while I need to output the rate with added `%` instead. How do I need to modify `'label'     => $rates[0]['title'].' ',` to output the rate instead of the title?

Answer (score 0):

*Facepalm* Well that was easy

> $rates[0]['percent'].'%',

I am certain I tried this earlier though and it wouldn't work...